# Search, insert, move and insert

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, aix

I want to search each record (records are defined by blank lines) in a file for the pattern `NAME#AAAA`. If it matches, then insert an `#` in front of the record's `AGE` line and move that line to the top of the paragraph. Then insert the line `AGE NIL` at the end:

INPUT FILE:

```
NAME#AAAA
STD 1
SEC A
AGE 5

NAME#BBBB
STD 2
SEC B
AGE 6


NAME#CCCC
STD 3
SEC C
AGE 7

NAME#AAAA
STD 4
AGE 9


NAME#AAAA
STD 7
SEC A
AGE 12
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
#AGE 5
NAME#AAAA
STD 1
SEC A
AGE NIL

NAME#BBBB
STD 2
SEC B
AGE 6

NAME#CCCC
STD 3
SEC C
AGE 7

#AGE 9
NAME#AAAA
STD 4
AGE NIL

#AGE 12
NAME#AAAA
STD 7
SEC A
AGE NIL
```

Also, I need the inverse of it. Just to revert the back the changes done. Please note that I am doing all this on an AIX machine.

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your posts clearly. Also, are you using AIX? If so, please mention that explicitly in your question since that limits the tools we can suggest.

Comment: oh :( ..Yes. I'm using AIX.

Comment: Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for `ex`, the POSIX-specified tool of choice for file editing.

(If you've ever used `vi`, by the way, you are likely familiar with `ex` since everything you type in `vi` that starts with a colon `:` is an `ex` command.  `ex` is the predecessor of `vi`.)

```
printf %s\\n 'g/NAME#AAAA/ /AGE/t- | s/^/#/ | /AGE/s/.*/AGE NIL/' x | ex input.txt
```

If you want to test it before you actually save the file, change the final `x` before the pipe symbol into `%p` and the modified file won't be saved, but the modified version will be printed to `stdout`.  So here is the testing command:

```
printf %s\\n 'g/NAME#AAAA/ /AGE/t- | s/^/#/ | /AGE/s/.*/AGE NIL/' %p | ex input.txt
```

---

**Explanation:**

`printf %s\\n` provides an easy way to feed multiple commands to `ex` with a newline after each.

`g/regex/` is the global command; it runs the commands which follow (up to the next newline) on each line that matches the given regex.

`/AGE/t-` copies the next line which matches the pattern `/AGE/` to a position just before the current line (which is the `NAME#AAAA` line).  It also moves the cursor to the new copy of the line (so that now becomes the "current line").

`|` is a command separator in `ex`.

`s/^/#/` prefixes the copied `AGE` line with a hashtag.  (Or a pound sign, depending on your dialect.)  ;)

The next command really has two parts: `/AGE/` is the address, which makes this command operate on the next line which contains that pattern, and `s/.*/AGE NIL/` replaces whatever that line was, with `AGE NIL`.

`x` saves the changes to the file and exits.

---

**Reversing the changes**

To reverse the changes, I would do the following:

```
printf %s\\n 'g/NAME#AAAA/ ?^#AGE? m /^AGE/ | s/^#// | -d' %p | ex input.txt
```

Then when the change was verified, actually save the changes with:

```
printf %s\\n 'g/NAME#AAAA/ ?^#AGE? m /^AGE/ | s/^#// | -d' x | ex input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

Global command as before.

Take the line that starts with `#AGE` from before the NAME line, move it after the next line that starts with `AGE`.

Remove the leading `#`.

Delete the immediately preceding line with `-d` (which is the NIL age line).

Print or save changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=""} 
          s/^(NAME#AAAA.*\n)(AGE.*?)(\n+)$/#$2\n$1AGE NIL$3/s' ex1
```

very brief explanations:

```
For all the registers in input                 |  perl -p
   separator= one or more empty lines          |     BEGIN{$/=""}
do:
  | substitute                                 |     s/
  |   ^(NAME AAAA.*\n)(AGE.*?)(\n+)$           |       regex /
  |    1              2       3                | 
  | by                                         |      /subst. string including
  |   # $2 \n  $1   AGE NIL   $3               |       capture groups/
  |                                            |
  | and print                                  |  ...from option -p
```

Update:

> Is if possible to have variables in place of NAME#AAAA ?

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN{
       $/=""; 
       $f=shift;  }
    s/^(NAME#$f.*\n)(AGE.*?)(\n+)$/#$2\n$1AGE NIL$3/s' AAAA  ex1
```

In this version we must provide a *pattern* argument (Eg: "AAAA"):

- line 4 : get first argument from the command line ("AAAA") and store it in $f
- line 5 : expand $f in the substitute pattern.

Comment: This would really be improved with an explanation of the pieces, even if very succinct.  Would you mind adding that?  :)

Comment: @Wildcard, lets do it! (sorry to be so lazy); brief explanation added.

Comment: Is if possible to have variables in place of NAME#AAAA  like                                                       printf %s\\n 'g/$line/ /AGE/t- | s/^/#/ | /AGE/s/.*/AGE NIL/' %p | ex input.txt

Comment: @user4432340, pleas see if my update is what you need.

Comment: @JJoao - thanks a bunch..  The pattern will be provide by the while read line. I will be using this inside the while                                               perl -pe '
    BEGIN{
       $/=""; } 
    s/^(**$line**.*\n)(AGE.*?)(\n+)$/#$2\n$1AGE NIL$3/s' file.txt   will this work?

Comment: @user4432340, generically in bash variable interpolation is obtained in double quoted strings `"..."` but not in single quoted strings `'...'` .  Try `echo 'line is $line !' `  then `echo "line is $line !"` and `echo 'line is ' $line '!'`  to see the differences.

Comment: @user4432340, so... `printf %s\\n 'g/$line/ /AGE/t- | s/^/#/ | /AGE/s/.*/AGE NIL/' %p | ex input.txt` will fail but `printf %s\\n 'g/'$line'/ /AGE/t- | s/^/#/ | /AGE/s/.*/AGE NIL/' %p | ex input.txt` will have interpolation

Comment: @JJoao - is it possible to get the inverse of this? Just to revert back the changes done or to change it how it was before running the printf?

Comment: @user4432340, I updated my answer with a reversal step.

Comment: @JJoao, also note that if you're embedding a variable in the code, (a) you should put it in double quotes, e.g. `'g/'"$line"'/ /AGE/...` to avoid whitespace splitting by the shell following variable expansion and (b) realize it will be handled as a regex, not as a fixed string (so any periods or asterisks may not do what you expect) and (c) ensure you don't have any `/` characters in the `$line` or else the characters after them will be taken as `ex` commands.

Comment: @wildcard, thank you for fix and for the good practices suggested. My idea with the previous comments was just to explain the basic interpolation rules of bash (I believe it is important for the raised questions). I personally don't like and try to avoid bash commands with mix quotations . In this situation a prefer a script with parameters...

Comment: @wildcard - thanks you so much for your advice.. I will consider the three points while using this Statement. Thanks again ...